# Ios Simulator for ubuntu

Tags: ide

I want to develop Ios React native app on Ubuntu but not able to find Simulator to run and test my app

Is there is any way to install Xcode or any other tool to run Ios app via Simulator like android studio used for android.

Comment: Not without violating Apple's terms of service. Reference: [Moderators are *not* the Software Police!](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17574/moderators-are-not-the-software-police-read-for-details)